# Including a function inside single quotes

Tags: php, function, urlencode

I am trying to figure out why I can't include a function into this. I am trying to make it so `$client` will make it's way into the request string. `http://test.com/next.xml?file=$client&test=againtest`

`$client` IS DEFINED as text from my database.

```
function update($pro){
    $request = 'http://test.com/next.xml?file='.$client'&'.'test='.urlencode($pro);;
    $postargs = 'status='.urlencode($pro);
    return $this->process($request,$postargs); 
}
```

Is there a certain way to do this? This doesn't give me any PHP errors, but it's not working right. If I remove `'.$client.'` and replace it with just plain text such as `text` it works, but when I include it as a function, it won't work.

Comment: shouldn't there be a dot after the .$client and between '&'

Comment: It should give you an error since you forgot a `.` between `$client'&'` and have a redundant `;` at the end of that same line. But that are probably just copy & paste errors.

Comment: If $client is defined as text from your database, then it is defined outside of that functions / methods scope. if you're inside an object and $client is defined on that object, you have to use $this->client instead of $client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `$client` isn't defined.

If that variable is defined out of the function's scope, it will not be available unless you define it as a global variable

`global $client`

This is discouraged though, a better way of doing this is to pass `$client` as a parameter to the function

Have a look here for more on variable scopes http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code like this, you forget about string concatenation:

```
$request = 'http://test.com/next.xml?file=' . $client . '&test=' . urlencode($pro);
```

Use whitespaces between dots and strings - just make a rule for this. And you will see all you typos!